# How can I do API Resources pagination?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I created an API and made customizations. Looking through the documentation, I tried a few ways, but somehow I could not do the pagination. Can you help me?

PostResource.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PostResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'            => $this->id,
            'image'         => $this->image,
            'description'   => $this->description,
            'created_at'    => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at'    => $this->updated_at,
            'user'          => new UserResource($this->user),
            'comments'      => CommentResource::collection($this->comment),
        ];
    }
}
```

PostController.php

```
public function res() {
        $post_all_item = Posts::all();
        return response()->json(PostResource::collection($post_all_item),200);

    }
```

Comment: you're fetching `all` data instead of `paginate(10)`

Comment: I am getting such an error `Call to a member function first() on null`

Comment: please give a detailed stack trace, only error is not helpful.

Comment: This is exactly the part that the error points to `return response()->json(PostResource::collection($post_all_item),200);`

Comment: do you have separate collection resource file? [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections)

Comment: No I don't have a reference file

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace as requested earlier? Without that it will be very difficult to understand the error since it's not related to the code shown above.

Comment: Can you help me how do I post this

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can paginate collections in laravel:

```
$post_all_item = Posts::paginate(15); //will paginate 15 posts per page
return PostResource::collection($post_all_item); //will be converted to Json automatically
```

Note1: Model names should be singularis eg. `Post` instead of `Posts`

Note2: Its not necessary to convert a resource collection to json response, Laravel will do that automatically

Note3: In resource files, check if relationships exists by using `whenLoaded`:

```
'user'     => new UserResource($this->whenLoaded('user')), //with resource
'comments' => $this->whenLoaded('comments'), //without resource
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it doesn't work. I'm getting the error I stated `Call to a member function first() on null`

Comment: Where do you get that? We need to see more of the stack trace to be able to help you

Comment: I don't know how to share this as I am new here. Can you help me?

Comment: You should really go back to reading the basics about how to use stackoverflow. You cant do it like this, with all respect here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask